# How to limit the number of record associations get printed when rendering json in respond_to

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4

I've had trouble understanding how this really works. My problem is this

### **Stuffs Controller**

```
  def refresh_stuffs
    id = params[:stuff][:id]
    last_update = params[:stuff][:last_update]

    @stuff = Stuff.find(id)
    @stuff.events.where('? < updated_at','2014-06-25 21:57:52') # The updated_at attr is 2014-06-19 22:59:15 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {
        render json: @stuff, status: :ok,
        include: {
          events: {except: [:created_at, :updated_at, :visible]}
        },
        except: [:created_at, :updated_at, :user_id]
      }
    end
  end
```

Now rendering works great except for one thing, when I want to render the associations as well it does not let me limit it. Everything I see talks about limiting which columns to show, I want to limit the amount of records that are accessed. Currently even the record I am trying to strip out using the `where` query above is showing up. How exactly are the associations queried when rendered in json? What can I do to filter it the way I want to?

**Example output**: `{"id":2, "name": "le name", "events": [{"id": 2, "etc":""}]`

**What I should get with the above example code**: `{"id":2, "name": "le name", "events":[]`

Comment: Your answer doesnt solve my problem

Comment: I add a new answer to  prove my code is working, if you think this answer cannot solve your problem, can you provide your research information?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try limit method?

I tested my project, it works well, I hope it will be usefull to you.

My project have a Dataset model have many Columns.

```
irb(main):026:0> Dataset.first.columns.count
  [1m[36mDataset Load (5.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT datasets.* FROM datasets FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY [0m
  [1m[35m (4.0ms)[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM columns WHERE columns.dataset_id = 1
=> 9
```

Using limit, you can controll the result of columns.

```
irb(main):048:0> dataset = Dataset.first
  [1m[36mDataset Load (10.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT datasets.* FROM datasets FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY [0m
irb(main):049:0> dataset.columns.where(nil).limit(3)
  [1m[35mColumn Load (11.0ms)[0m  SELECT columns.* FROM columns WHERE columns.dataset_id = 1 ORDER BY id
FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY
```

You can see, the sql generated by ActiveRecord if different.

**But when you render json, the render method may recall the colums method (in your case is events method), so active_record may post a new query to the db server.**

**To solve the problem, you can use includes before where to get two associated models data at once, just like this:**

```
irb(main):056:0> dataset = Dataset.includes(:columns).where('columns.id = ?',30809).first
  [1m[35mSQL (7.0ms)[0m  SELECT datasets.id FROM datasets LEFT OUTER JOIN columns ON 
columns.dataset_id = datasets.id WHERE (columns.id = 30809) FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
irb(main):058:0> dataset.columns.size
=> 1
```

If you use includes with where, ActiveRecored will generate join statment for you.

In your case, try this version.

```
def refresh_stuffs
  id = params[:stuff][:id]
  last_update = params[:stuff][:last_update]

  @stuff = Stuff.includes(:events)
    .where('stuffs.id = ? and ? < events.updated_at',id,'2014-06-25 21:57:52') # The updated_at attr is 2014-06-19 22:59:15 
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {
      render json: @stuff, status: :ok,
      include: {
        events: {except: [:created_at, :updated_at, :visible]}
      },
      except: [:created_at, :updated_at, :user_id]
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't want to literally limit it. That would work, but I want to filter a larger dataset using something similar to a where clause. As far as I can tell its re-querying in order to do this.

Comment: Can you describe your case more specifically?

Comment: Sure, i think I'll just update the question with an example output and what I expect. But basically lets say the model `Stuff` has_many  `Events`. Now I want to allow access to `Stuff` and any updated `Events` (relative to when a user last updated). So when I render I only expect to get any `Event` that has an `updated_at` column that is greater than the `latest_update`. The above example does not do that. it just gets all events associated to `Stuff`.

Comment: Could you do a code example with my above Models and where clause? I tried that already and it hasn't worked. I should also mention the point is not to get 1. It is to filter out what has an `updated_at` greater than the user `last_update`. This can be 0 through any number of `Events`.

Comment: `@stuff = Stuff.includes(:events).where('stuffs.id = ? and ? < events.updated_at',id,last_update)` may be what you want. But you should know, includes just a kind of method to implentment SQL join clause, and with where method , you can generate any filter clause you like, but don't forget add table name prefix before column name.

Answer (score 0):

I add a new answer for you, and it worked in my project.

Controller code:

```
  # GET /datasets/1/test
  # GET /datasets/1/test.json
  def test
    @project_id = params[:project_id]
    @dataset = Dataset.includes(:columns).where('datasets.id = ? and columns.id < ?',params[:id],params[:max_col_id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
        format.json {
          render json: @dataset, status: :ok,
          include: {
            columns: {only: [:id]}

          },
          only: [:id]
        }
    end
  end
```

**Test result:**

```
url1:  http://localhost:3000/datasets/9657/test.json?max_col_id=433612
return data1: [{"id":9657,"columns":[{"id":433609},{"id":433608},{"id":433610},{"id":433611}]}]
```

**Return 4 members of columns model.**

```
url2: http://localhost:3000/datasets/9657/test.json?max_col_id=433611
return data2: [{"id":9657,"columns":[{"id":433609},{"id":433608},{"id":433610}]}]
```

**Return only 3 members of columns model. Done!**

I didn't use time_stamp to filter sub model, because different dbms may have different way to compare time_stamp.

Sorry for my poor English. I'll try my best to write clearly. Any advise to improve my answer will be appreciated.